# Save as output layer from QGIS processing algorithm to PostGIS database using PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have two layers(layer1,layer2) in PostGIS database where I have connect in QGIS project.

My database have specific precision. Now I want to use from QGIS processing some algorithms like GISDIFFERENCE(for example I know tew postgis have query for this). But I don't know how to import the algorithm output in PostGIS database automatic to keep my database precision.

For example, if I try to run graphical this tool show me choose to save as to PostGIS database. Because I want to create a QGIS plugin.

Some way is to run algorithms and I save manual the output to shapefile and after to import this shapefile to PostGIS database like this :

```
outputs_QGISDIFFERENCE_1=processing.runalg('qgis:difference', layer1,layer2,False,None)
load= QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISDIFFERENCE_1['OUTPUT'],'myname', 'ogr')
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load)
```

and save to PostGIS database.

But that way create it me topology error because I loose the database precision if I use the graphical way to save as to PostGIS database then that layer is correct.

But how to do this using PyQGIS?

Comment: Still interested in this question?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using something like this:

```
def updateOriginalLayer(self, pgInputLayer, qgisOutputVector):
        """
        Updates the original posts layer using the processing output layer
        pgInputLyr: postgis input layer
        qgisOutputVector: qgis processing output layer
        """
        provider = pgInputLayer.dataProvider()
        # getting keyColumn because we want to be generic
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI(pgInputLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
        keyColumn = uri.keyColumn()
        # starting edition mode
        pgInputLayer.startEditing()
        addList = []
        idsToRemove = []
        #making the changes and inserts
        for feature in pgInputLayer.getFeatures():
            id = feature.id()
            outFeats = []
            #getting the output features with the specific id
            if qgisOutputVector:
                for gf in qgisOutputVector.dataProvider().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("{0}={1}".format(keyColumn, id)))):
                    outFeats.append(gf)
            #starting to make changes
            for i in range(len(outFeats)):
                if i == 0:
                    #let's update this feature
                    newGeom = outFeats[i].geometry()
                    newGeom.convertToMultiType()
                    feature.setGeometry(newGeom)
                    pgInputLayer.updateFeature(feature)
                else:
                    #for the rest, let's add them
                    newFeat = QgsFeature(feature)
                    newGeom = outFeats[i].geometry()
                    newFeat.setGeometry(newGeom)
                    idx = newFeat.fieldNameIndex(keyColumn)
                    newFeat.setAttribute(idx, provider.defaultValue(idx))
                    addList.append(newFeat)
            #in the case we don't find features in the output we should mark them to be removed
            if len(outFeats) == 0:
                idsToRemove.append(id)
        #pushing the changes into the edit buffer
        pgInputLayer.addFeatures(addList, True)
        #removing features from the layer
        pgInputLayer.deleteFeatures(idsToRemove)
```